# Isolating a link from a hyperlink pasted into an input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a situation where users will need to paste in a hyperlink and the app must parse the link attached to the text given.

For example, a user pastes [Bob Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/randomlinkgiven)

I would like to grab the link attached to this hyperlinked name and store it in a variable (I am using JQuery)

Copying and pasting the hyperlinked name simply gives me raw text in the input field, so I am unable to get the link.

I would appreciate any help/insight.

UPDATE: To see what I mean, simply copy and paste [Test Link](http://example.com) into Google Sheets. You'll see that Sheets recognizes the hyperlink. How can I do that or something similar?

Comment: Still vague. Can you explain more?

Comment: Sure. Suppose you copy and paste [Test Link](http://example.com) into an input field. Once pasted the text no longer has the link associated with it. I want the link.

Comment: You can't copy them both unless you're copying the source code of the link.

Comment: How are you copying it?

Comment: I want users to literally just copy and paste [Test Link](http://example.com) into an input field and somehow get the link. Google Sheets has this functionality. Go ahead and copy and paste [Test Link](http://example.com) into a Google Sheet. You will see that the link is recognized by Sheets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Online Spreadsheets hook Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V and transfer focus to a hidden textarea. They then read the text in the textarea.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the input. Could you give example code though? I can mark this as the right answer after, if it works.

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: @szier Are the links comming from within the page or could the user copy them from anywhere?

Comment: The user could copy them from anywhere. For example, I could copy [ibrahim mahrir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6647153/ibrahim-mahrir) from this page, paste it in, and I'd like to grab the link.

Comment: Haha obviously not if Google Sheets can do it. Go ahead and try it on Google Sheets. It also seems that @JakeBoggs knows of one way to do it so hopefully he can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Bind `'Paste'` on your `Input` Tag.

Access `Clipboard` Data to get text and html. Try Snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#source').bind('paste', function (e) {
// Prevent while Pasting Data 
    e.preventDefault();
// For Internet Explorer (not working)
    if( window.clipboardData )
    {
        var content1 = window.clipboardData.getData('text');
        $('#source').val(content1);
        $('#target').val("Use Other Browser to Avail this Facility.");
    }
// for Other Browsers (tested on FireFox, Chrome & EDGE)
    else if( e.originalEvent.clipboardData )
    {
        var plainText = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        var htmlText = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/html');
        var hrefArray = new Array();
// Store Html Data in Temporary Div
        var TempDiv = $('<div></div>').append(htmlText);
// Get HREF of each Anchor Tag
        $('a', TempDiv).each(function(){
            hrefArray.push($(this).attr('href'));
        });
        $('#source').val(plainText);
        $('#target').val(hrefArray.join('\r'));
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Copy & Paste this line <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript">Link1</a> <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html">Link2</a> into input textbox<br>

<input type=text id=source style="width:400px; border: solid 1px #000;">
<br>
<textarea id=target style="width:400px; height:200px; border: solid 1px #000;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from coworkers I was able to do this:

**index.html**

```
<div contenteditable="true"">
Paste something...

</div>
```

**test.js**

```
$(function(){
    $("div").on("paste", function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log($("div").html());
        },100);
    });        
});
```

Setting `contenteditable="true"` and then grabbing the HTML via `$("div").html()` allowed me to store it in a variable and parse through it to get the link attached to a hyperlink once pasted into the `<div>`